# Force Fields > Gravitation math buggy?

Tags: python, mathematics, force-fields

My objects disappear when activating the 'Gravitation' option (5:30 of this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bcqLZJcTSY). It looks like the equation 1/distance^2 maybe isn't working?

Edit: So I looked into the source and in blender-master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/effect.c I found this snippet. I can't read it well enough, but:

- strength = 0 I hope is only between object centroids, not surfaces. maybe this is why off-center collisions in zero-gravity don't keep spinning forever
- is powf and -2.0f correct to make the this 1/distance^2?

[image]

Comment: maybe this question is too hard to answer. should i submit a bug ticket? can anybody give me a replacement line of python code to try? i think the -2 is breaking this. Can python magically multiply by a negative power? Or does the f contain another -? Or is there something i dont understand about the code?